# Highlight slice of a pie chart in highcarts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I would like to highlight a piece of pie chart like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/johndierks/mgadm39m/2/
however I cannot use `chart.series[0].data[0].setState('hover');` method in because it's called after the chart is rendered and I don't have control over that because of the way my app is made. Is there any way to achieve something like this directly in chart definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [load](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load) event.

```
events: {
          load: function () {
            this.series[0].data[0].setState('hover');
          }
        }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/mgadm39m/4/